# log catpture did not start in resonable amount of time , while launching safari in ios real device and appium:

Tags: ios, selenium-rc, appium

log catpture did not start in resonable amount of time , while launching safari in ios real device and appium:

I used xcode 6.1 (As it supports ios sdk 8.1)

APPIUM VERSION's used : (1.2.2, 1.3.4, 1.36 )

as suggested in one of the posts i cleared device logs in x-code console. but still facing the same error. can anyone please suggest me how to get it fixed and run scripts in safari in real ios device (ios 8.1)

Answer (score 1):

Launching Safari on a real device is a total PITA, but it's hard to see exactly what the problem is here without more information. Can you post the appium log so we can see what was happening before the error occurred?

Make sure you have followed all the steps in the [appium doc](http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?java#mobile-safari-on-a-real-ios-device) - you have to build SafariLauncher and deploy it to the phone, and build ios-webkit-debug-proxy and start it up before you can start appium and run your tests.

Comment: I have followed all the steps mentioned in the Appium Doc.Built  SafariLauncher by providig all the certificates and provisioning profile and deploy it to the iPhone (Version 8.1), then installed ios-webkit-debug-proxy and started it before  starting appium and running tests.and i got the error Log capture didnot start in reasonable amount of time.

Comment: :Appium log
info: [debug] Error: Log capture did not start in a reasonable amount of time at null._onTimeout (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/lib/devices/ios/ios-log.js:137:10)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:110:15)
info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: Log capture did not start in a reasonable amount of time)","origValue":"Log capture did not start in a reasonable amount of time"},"sessionId":null}
info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 10288.036 ms - 234

Comment: I was unable to post the whole appium log in this comment .. so i just mentioned the line which showed log not captured. @jon_two